# Marklogic exception handling

Tags: javascript, error-handling, marklogic

I would like to develop such module in MarkLogic JS API:
If conditional checking is good, then proceed the next code blocks. If not, then besides try/catch, how can I exit the whole module? 
The purpose is that I can not only get the error message, exit the module safely but I don't need to encapsulate all the codes inside the try/catch. 
Is there such function in MarkLogic?  I couldn't find it. And lots of JS (not MarkLogic JS API) error handling doesn't work in MarkLogic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not understand the problem correctly, but I'll offer a few suggestions:

- To exit a module due to a failure condition, you can use the fn.error() function http://docs.marklogic.com/fn.error
- To do the equivalent of a return in a JavaScript main module, one simple approach is to move all of the code into a function and call the function, which can then return at any point.

Hoping that's useful,